# Golang Server Timeout

Tags: go

I have a very simple go server:

```
package main

import(
  "net/http"
  "fmt"
  "log"
)

func test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  fmt.Println("No bid")
  http.Error(w, "NoBid", 204)
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/test/bid", test)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
  log.Println("Done serving")
}
```

I then run the apache benchmark tool:

```
ab -c 50 -n 50000 -p post.txt http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/bid
```

The Server runs and responds to about 15000 requests and then times out. I was wondering why this happens and if there is something I can do about this.

Comment: try running your executable in the following way: `nohup ./[name]`

Comment: Did you try and close the Request.Body?

Comment: What error are you getting (if any?). Chances are you are starved of open sockets on your operating system. I'd also recommend using wrk (https://github.com/wg/wrk) or weighttp (https://github.com/lighttpd/weighttp) instead of Apache Bench.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I could not get nohup or r.Body.Close to alleviate my problem. I will check out the other benchmarking tools and see if I can find anything.

Comment: I started to use wrk and I think it is better for what I am doing, thank you much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you running in Linux, Maybe too many open files, so it can't create connection, You need change system config to support more connections.

For example,

edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` add

```
*    soft    nofile 100000
*    soft    nofile 100000
```

To open more file.

edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
# use more port
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65000
# keep alive timeout
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 300
# allow reuse
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
# quick recovery
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to replicate your problem on my linux amd64 laptop with no success - it worked fine even with

```
ab -c 200 -n 500000 -p post.txt http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/bid
```

There were about 28,000 sockets open though which may be bumping a limit on your system.

A more real world test might be to turn keepalives on which maxes out at 400 sockets

```
ab -k -c 200 -n 500000 -p post.txt http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/bid
```

The result for this was

```
Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /test/bid
Document Length:        6 bytes

Concurrency Level:      200
Time taken for tests:   33.807 seconds
Complete requests:      500000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    500000
Total transferred:      77000000 bytes
Total body sent:        221500000
HTML transferred:       3000000 bytes
Requests per second:    14790.04 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       13.523 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.068 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2224.28 [Kbytes/sec] received
                        6398.43 kb/s sent
                        8622.71 kb/s total

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0      11
Processing:     0   14   5.2     13      42
Waiting:        0   14   5.2     13      42
Total:          0   14   5.2     13      42

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     13
  66%     16
  75%     17
  80%     18
  90%     20
  95%     21
  98%     24
  99%     27
 100%     42 (longest request)
```

I suggest you try `ab` with `-k` and take a look at tuning your system for lots of open sockets